# failed to open the x11 display : unable to connect

Tags: linux, ssh, x11-forwarding

The server that supports the graphical display is different from the server I'm sshed into. When I try to open virtualbox, I get this message.

```
$ Failed to open the X11 display!
```

When I try to startx, I get three error messages.

```
$ PAM authentication failed, cannot start X server

$ giving up.
$ xinit:  No such file or directory (errno 2):  unable to connect to X server
$ xinit:  No such process (errno 3):  Server error.
```

I don't know where the display variable is, as I'm very new to linux.  Any straightforward advice and help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give option -X on command line to enable X11 forwarding (graphical interfaces).

```
ssh -X user@hostname
```

It can be also enabled per host basis by setting "ForwardX11" to "yes" in configuration file (~/.ssh/config). Support for X11 forwarding needs to be also enabled in the target server's sshd configuration file (/etc/ssh/sshd_config) with option `X11Forwarding yes`.

You should also know that there are some security implications in enabling the X11 forwarding. Read more from ssh and sshd man pages or [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/security-concerns-with-x11-forwarding). If you control both server and client and trust both equally, there shouldn't be any problem in enabling the forwarding.

Comment: I have one minor issue here.  I have to ssh into the server, then a cluster of that server;  Forwarding didn't seem to work when I tried it.

Comment: It should work also chained. Did you specify -X flag in both connections and do both servers allow X11 forwarding in sshd_config? You can also try with -Y option which is insecure version of the forwarding, but in some cases allows more things to be done.

Comment: I have ForwardX11Trusted set to yes for the graphical server, and the ssh server.

so
'ssh -X server', 'ssh -X clusternocde',  and -Y didn't seem to function.
I've also tried 'export DISPLAY graphicalserver:0.0' and that failed as well.

Comment: The correct setting in sshd_config is `X11Forwarding yes`. Remember to restart the ssh with `service ssh restart`. I added this information also to the answer.

Comment: Amusingly, I had this problem trying to launch virutalbox as root locally in order to update the guest additions (Not sure why it wouldn't work locally). That is to be precise, ssh -X root@localhost and then running VirtualBox from that ssh session on localhost worked like a charm.